# Webservice iPhone

Tags: iphone, web-services

I am trying to access a webservice (written in .NET) from my iPhone application.

This is my code:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

    NSString *postString =[NSString stringWithFormat:question];
    NSLog(postString);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: address+@"/execute"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]];

    [req addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setHTTPBody: [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    if (conn) {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }


}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response {
    [webData setLength: 0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection
    didReceiveData:(NSData *) data {
    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *) error {
    [webData release];
    [connection release];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc]
                        initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes]
                        length:[webData length]
                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //---shows the XML---
    NSLog(theXML);
    [theXML release];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    if (xmlParser)
    {
        [xmlParser release];
    }
    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate: self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
    [xmlParser parse];

    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}
```

It's entering the didReceiveResponse and didReceiveData methods but the following text is retrieved instead of the data I want:

> > Runtime Error
> >             
> >              body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:
> >     .7em;color:black;} 
> >              p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
> >              b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top:
> >     -5px}
> >              H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red
> >     }
> >              H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon
> >     }
> >              pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}
> >              .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
> >              .version {color: gray;}
> >              .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
> >              .expandable { text-decoration:underline;
> >     font-weight:bold; color:navy;
> >     cursor:hand; }
>
> ```
> <body bgcolor="white">
>
>         <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr
> ```
>
> width=100initWithBytes:length:encoding:ize=1
>   color=silver>
>
> ```
>         <h2> <i>Runtime Error</i> </h2></span>
>
>         <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular,
> ```
>
> sans-serif ">
>
> ```
>         <b> Description: </b>An application error occurred on the
> ```
>
> server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent
>   the details of the application error
>   from being viewed remotely (for
>   security reasons). It could, however,
>   be viewed by browsers running on the
>   local server machine.
>
> ```
>         <b>Details:</b> To enable the details of this specific error
> ```
>
> message to be viewable on remote
>   machines, please create a
>   <customErrors> tag within a
>   "web.config" configuration
>   file located in the root directory of
>   the current web application. This
>   <customErrors> tag should then
>   have its "mode" attribute
>   set to "Off".
>
> ```
>         <table width=100 gcolor="#ffffcc">
>            <tr>
>               <td>
>                   <code><pre>
> ```
>
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File
>   -->
>
> <configuration>
>       <system.web>
>           <customErrors mode="Off"/>
>       </system.web> </configuration>
>
> ```
>               </td>
>            </tr>
>         </table>
>
>         <br>
>
>         <b>Notes:</b> The current error page you are seeing can be
> ```
>
> replaced by a custom error page by
>   modifying the
>   "defaultRedirect" attribute
>   of the application's
>   <customErrors> configuration tag
>   to point to a custom error page
>   URL.
>
> ```
>         <table width=100 gcolor="#ffffcc">
>            <tr>
>               <td>
>                   <code><pre>
> ```
>
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File
>   -->
>
> <configuration>
>       <system.web>
>           <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"
>   defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
>       </system.web> </configuration>
>
> ```
>               </td>
>            </tr>
>         </table>
>
>         <br>
>
> </body> </html>
> ```

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You get server side error. Check request parameters you send to a web-service from your iPhone app.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a conflict between the actual message length and the length set in the "Content-Length" header.

One is set by getting the length of the string and the other is set by getting a data using UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Thanks for answering, so what would I need to change?

Comment: Do you need to explicitly set the content-length?

Comment: i commented out :
[req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [req setHTTPBody: [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

and i still got the same error

Comment: Then could be some malformed parameters in your post data. It's impossible to tell without knowing what it is supposed to be.